# Dynamically formatting headers in react-table using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table, react-table-v7

The full code can be found here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-allen-sn6os?file=/src/App.tsx

What I am trying to do is render a table using `react-table` and would like to dynamically generate the columns array containing the Headers, accessors and Cell attributes and set them dynamically based on the types of values present within a given data set.

In the code sample above, for example, the data is an array of todos and I am trying to set the Column Headers & Cell Values text to align right if their type is a `number` by checking the type of cell values present in the data set.

However, I am having problems getting to render the Headers attribute.

The following is mentioned in the docs and I believe I am returning valid JSX, but I may be doing something wrong here and any help would be greatly appreciated in resolving this issue! Thank you.

https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable

```
Header: String | Function | React.Component => JSX
- Optional
- Defaults to () => null
- Receives the table instance and column model as props
- Must either be a string or return valid JSX
- If a function/component is passed, it will be used for formatting the header value, eg. You can use a Header function to dynamically format the header using any table or column state.
```

Comment: Your header is rendered, it's just 0  height if you add content within the div in the header you will be able to see it. [https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-kare-w00rz](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-kare-w00rz)

Comment: Thanks for the solution to get the Header rendered. Seems like I was making a horrible rookie mistake. And, is there any way to get rid of the type mismatch error for `columns` at line 13?